# Highchart - Set Time(Hour:Minute) on X axis

Tags: highcharts

I did not able to get labels like [12:00,12:15,12:30,12:45,01:00,01:15,..] on X axis.
I got only 00:00 on X axis.I was not able to display increasing time values on X axes.
I want to start default from 12:00.

I used following code.

xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval : 1.5 * 3600 * 1000,
            dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                                   day : '%H:%M'
                                   }
                }

Comment: i think for after 11:59 pm it is taking as 0:00 am

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Dynamic Highchart.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sensor Data Vs. Time'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Value',
                    margin: 80
                }
            },

            series: [{
               name: 'Sensor Data',
                data: []
            }]
});
});
```

With this I am displaying Hours, Minutes and seconds as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us what data you are supplying. Something like this works:

```
        series: [{
            name: 'Temperatures',
            pointStart: new Date().getTime(),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, 
            data: [1.5 * 60 * 1000,1.2 * 60 * 1000,2.5 * 60 * 1000,1.9 * 60 * 1000,],
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/pQ5EC/12/